# Does snakemake lock output directories

Tags: python, parallel-processing, snakemake

Snakemake locks output files as stated in the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-does-snakemake-lock-the-working-directory), but what about output directories?

I have multiple files in a directory that are read and written to by possibly multiple processes at the same time. I want to make sure that only one process at a time has access to the files in this directory. However, the exact set of files is determined dynamically and might be different for each spawned process. Therefore I cannot simply specify these critical files as output files in the rule s.t. they are locked by snakemake.

Is it enough to add `directory(my_dir)` to the output of the rule? Does snakemake lock recursively all files in any subdirectory of the output folder?

Answer (score 0):

Per the snakemake documentation [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-does-snakemake-lock-the-working-directory), it sounds like output files will be locked as snakemake touches them. By including the directory you want to lock in the output, this should theoretically ensure that the two rules cannot touch them at the same time.

One **major**, the caveat is that, as described the documentation [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs), snakemake deletes all outputs (including directories listed as outputs) before running jobs which could be problematic depending on your workflow.